# Is it possible to find the supremum of $\{+\infty\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, infinity

**EDIT:**

I wonder how the supremum of $\{+\infty\}$ is determined. In fact, *Baby Rudin* suggests that $s^{*}\in E$ even if $s^{*}=+\infty$ (*Theorem 3.17*):

> If $s^{*}=+\infty$, then $E$ is not bounded above; hence $\{s_{n}\}$ is not bounded above, and there is a subsequences $\{s_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $s_{n_{k}}\to+\infty$.

Does it suggest that $+\infty\le+\infty$ (hence $+\infty$ qualifies as a upper bound)? **If so, what's the reason that a set with its supremum is not bounded above, which totally makes no sense.**

Comment: What do you mean the order between $+\infty$ and $+\infty$ is not defined? They are equal!

Comment: @6005 Then, why did _Rudin_ suggest that **$E$ is not bounded above**? If $+\infty\in E$, aren't $E$ bounded above?

Comment: it depends on your definition of $+\infty$

Comment: Actually, I think it depends not on +infty but on your definition of bounded above.  Def 2.18.  i) E is *bounded* if there is a **REAL** [emph. mine, duh] number M and a point $q \in X$ such that d(p,q) < M for all $p \in E.  This is *not* the cause with E as even though +infty is a perfectly valid member of a set, it is never ever ever a real number.  This is a subtle point of topology and analysis.  No matter what space and metrics we are using, we are *ALWAYS* using real numbers as our measures of norms and metrics.

Comment: I have tried to answer your question, but let me know if there are more lingering questions. Note that we have no idea what $E$ is in the context of this baby rudin passage, or $s^*$ for that matter, so I can't address those things.

Comment: @marmouset ?? Actually it does not. No cognitive relativism where it is not needed, please.

Comment: @6005 Thank you for answering. _Rudin_ suggests that **Let $E$ be the set of numbers $x$ (in the extended real number system) such that $s_{n_{k}}\to x$** for some subsequences $\{s_{n_{k}}\}$. For the case of $s^{*}$, it is the supremum of $E$.

Comment: @Il-seobBae I have now addressed the passage from Rudin in an addendum to my answer.

Comment: @Did sorry i pushed the wrong key. No offense. 6005 answer is perfect.

Comment: @fleablood Your comment is exactly what I have been looking for. If you had posted an answer, I would have accepted it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It was covered in 6005's answer pretty thoroughly.

Comment: @fleablood I also think that 6005's answer is great. I just liked your comment better because you provided a reference to _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be that you have gotten to used to thinking of $\infty$ as merely a concept: you have taken to heart that $\infty$ is not a number, but rather a stand-in for some limit of some sort. Therefore, let me stress that in this context $\infty$ *is* a number, specifically an "extended real number", and all the usual rules of an ordering on numbers apply.

Formally, the *extended real numbers* are given by the set
$$
\overline{\mathbb{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{-\infty, \infty\}.
$$
While addition and multiplication are only partially defined on this set, the ordering $\le$ is fully defined:

- $-\infty \le x$ for all $x \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$;
- $x \le \infty$ for all $x \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$; and
- If $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, with $x$ less than or equal to $y$ under the usual ordering on $\mathbb{R}$, then $x \le y$. (Therefore we do not need two different symbols for $\le$ of the reals and $\le$ of the extended reals.)

This makes $\le$ into a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) on $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
In particular, $\infty$ and $\infty$ are the same extended real number, so $\infty \le \infty$.

The useful thing is that any set of real numbers (or even any set of extended real numbers) has an infimum or supremum in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$.
In particular, $\infty$ is a perfectly valid least upper bound for a set.

Now, let me address the lingering problem: what does *bounded above* mean?
In analysis, "bounded above" will always be short for "bounded above by a **real number**" and not "bounded above by an **extended real number**".
The latter notion would not be so useful, because every set of real numbers is bounded above by $\infty$.
So we say that $S$ *bounded above* if there exists $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $s \le r$ for all $s \in S$.

**Addendum:**

In your excerpt from Rudin, $E$ is the set of limit points of a sequence $s_n$, and $s^*$ is the supremum of $E$. Let me translate / explain the passage:

> If $s^{*}=+\infty$, then $E$ is not bounded above;

This is true for the following reason: the least upper bound of $E$ is $\infty$, which in particular means that any finite extended real number $r$ is *not* an upper bound of $E$. So there is no $r \in \mathbb{R}$, hence $E$ is not **"bounded above"** by the above definition.

> hence $\{s_{n}\}$ is not bounded above, and there is a subsequences $\{s_{n_{k}}\}$ such that $s_{n_{k}}\to+\infty$.

If $s_n$ were bounded above by $r \in \mathbb{R}$, then all limits would be $\le r$, so this cannot be the case. Thus $s_n$ is not **"bounded above"** (again by the above definition), and there must be a subsequence which goes to $\infty$.

Comment: How can $\infty$ be a supremum of $E$? It's not a real number as you clearly stated.

Comment: What's the reason $E$ is not considered as _bounded above_ although it has the supremum $\infty$. I believe that the existence of a supremum naturally implies that the set involved is bounded above. I feel strong inconsistency in this point... In fact, removing the sentence "_then $E$ is not bounded above_" seems to perfectly make sense to me (I just don't feel the need for it.)

Comment: That's because the book defined **supremum** to be one of upper bounds, and an upper bound is really the same as bounded above. They are tightly connected so that what you just said is not consistent in the light of my book (I'm not saying that you're wrong, I just want to stick to the book's philosophy).

Comment: I really don't mean to hurt your feelings. I'm really sorry if you feel that way. I'm just trying to be "strict" because it's the right way to "treat" mathematics.

Comment: It's not that I'm "unwilling" to accept it, rather that I just didn't know it's a convention and needed some time to sleep on it. I'm also sorry to hear that I looked as if I enjoyed dissenting your opinions, but I'm just trying to prove my points with some valid references to the book. And... Yes. I admit that I tend to see things literally, especially learning mathematics. Anyway, I really appreciate your efforts to answer my question. Thank you...

Comment: I mistakenly pressed "move to chat". Please don't bother:).